# I am not able to change the position of my ck editor

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, ckeditor

I am not able to position my ck editor.

Below is the JS client code

```
  Template.a.onRendered(function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace('b');
    $('CKEDITOR').css({'position':'relative','left':'-40px', 'top': '5px'});
  });
```

After ck editor has replaced the editor id which in this case is "b". How do I change its position. The above method is not working. what is the correct method for doing that?
I am new to programming. So, please forgive me for any diversion from programming conventions. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: is it a custom tagname? like `<CKEDITOR>` else you missed a `#` or `.` I guess

Comment: It is a custom tag name. It replaces the textarea with ck editor. # or . is not needed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using pure css like this (use an ID or Class to select the Dom):

```
#my_ckeditor{
    position:'relative' !important;
    left:'-40px' !important;
    top: '5px' !important;
}
```

You can add an Id for the ckeditor, and then use this id as a selector for CSS.
Important! means that this style has the highest priority than the default CKeditor stylesheet.

Comment: I think that I cannot use this because I have used CKEDITOR in other places as well and it would change those ck editors positions as well

Comment: How will "!important" solve the problem ? Can you please explain a bit.

Comment: How do I use "my_ckeditor" id in the JS code? Please help here. Or rather how do I define my_ckeditor in JS code because if I use as it is, it will return a "not defined' error.

Comment: Hii. The ckeditor replaces your 'b' id with 'cke_b'. You can check this by using chrome tools or firefox tools and look at the source code. so you need to call #cke_b at your css or $("#cke_b") with js.

Comment: Thank you . It has solved my problem. Thank you so much. It was a very stupid question to ask at the end.